# Android emulator runs in device manager but not display in running device in android studio

Tags: android, android-emulator

System configuration : windows 11
Android studio version : Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 2

Using the device manager created virtual device with API level 33. The virtual device is shown in running device window and able to install app which have targetSDKVersion is 33 and minSDkVersion is 26.

After some time the virtual device created is vanished from the running device window , asking to recreate the same. But when I see in device manager or task manager its running, I am also able to run and install apk to same. But its not visible in running devices window.

Every time I have to kill android emulator in task manager and start again the process for developing.

please help  me on this I have tried many ways but its not working yet.